# Registry key creation or modification under localserver32 for c++ exe

Tags: c++, windows

Am new to c++ and need help regarding registry value modification or creation.

So, in registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT->CLSID->{asd12...}->LocalServer32->"c:\program files\myapp.exe"  is the value of the path of my exe with DOUBLE quotes

I have a c++ exe that gets registered when I run it or call it from another c++ exe in the above mentioned path with its path having double quotes which is the issue.

Whenever, my exe is opened standalone it works fine irrespective of double quotes in the registry but when my app is opened from another c++ exe it does not launch and says my app does not exist at the path because of the double quotes in the path.

So,I need help in writing or modifying the path to write in registry without quotes i.e, should I write the value or will it be there already when I am trying to do thisin my app?

Comment: As far as I can see, it is perfectly normal for a `LocalServer32` entry to have double quotes.  How exactly are you trying to run this from "another c++ exe"?  Post the code.

Comment: code searches for "myapp.application" and its value which will be the path with quotes. So, I need to remove it as they will not write logic to remove it because there are other apps whose path is stored without quotes.

Comment: Code I see,                                                                                  CMap<UINT, UINT&, LAUNCHOBJECT, LAUNCHOBJECT&> _mapClassName                     
  if(!m_mapClassName.Lookup(uCmdId,loTemp))
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

Comment: Please add any code to the question rather than putting it in a comment.  I don't see the relevance of that code fragment anyway, is the problem related to a dictionary lookup rather than to launching the application?

Comment: FWIW, it sounds as if whatever code is reading the value from the registry ought to be checking for and stripping out the quote marks before passing the value to the rest of the logic.  You shouldn't modify the registry entry itself.

Comment: ... except that it seems odd to be reading the value from the registry yourself in the first place.  Typically you would call ShellExecuteEx and give it a ProgId or a registry path, let Windows figure out how to find the executable.